# How do you set a composite Primary Key in Visio 2010?

Tags: visio, composite

Im working on an assignment where i have to create an EERD, and one of the entities (Bed) has an identifier key of Bed ID which is a composite attribute of bed# and Room #.

How should i go about setting this up as a single identifier?

Comment: I don't know for Visio, but generally you select both attributes/columns simultaneously and tell your editor to consider the grouping as the Primary key.

Comment: Please share the answer.